# $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $ prove that $|z|\le|x|+|y| \le \sqrt{2}|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $z$ is  a  complex  number , $|x|$ is the modulus of $x$, and $|y|$ the modulus of $y$, $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Prove that:

$$|z|\leq|x|+|y|\leq \sqrt{2}|z|$$

I tried: $|z|\leq|x|+|y|\le 2\sqrt{|x||y|}\leq\sqrt{2}|z|$ comparing arithmetic and geometric mean.

Comment: Please don't put everything into a formula between `\begin{align}...`. Text should be presented as text, entered by simply typing it.

Comment: Yes, this is some terrible formatting.

Comment: sorry ,  I'm new  in  this  site  ,  and  i  don't  know  how   it  works....

Comment: could  you help  me  with  this  question?

Comment: *Hint:* Try checking each inequality separately by squaring each side.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

For the first inequality: Use $ |x|^2 + |y|^2 \leq |x|^2 + 2|x||y| + |y|^2$.

For the second inequality: Show that $|x|^2 - 2|x||y| + |y|^2 \geq 0$.